# Translate magento product categories

Tags: mysql, magento, csv

I would like translate Magento store product categories without the use of `Admin` panel. Is it possible to change names directly through `database` / `.csv file` / wherever category names are stored. I think it would be much faster since i have a lot of categories to translate.